Tuples as operation outputs
I feel like I am going to ask a silly question out of ignorance, but....
If a relation is the subset of a Cartesian Product i.e. a set of tuples AND
A function is a particular kind of relation (with understood additional properties) AND
An operation is a function where the domains and the co-domain are all the same set THEN
How is it that the output of an operation is both a tuple and has the same type as the domains. In other words, how can a tuple type be the same as a non-tuple type? Is there a simple explanation for this (to me) apparent contradiction?

An $n$-ary operation on some group $G$ is a function
$$
f: G^n \to G
$$
The domain is not quite the same as the co-domain, but it is just a product of that space with itself, which has elements generally represented as tuples as you have stated. However, the output is just a single element (which you could represent as a 1 element tuple if you want).
On another note, a tuple is a perfectly valid "return type" for a function. For example, take a function as such:
\begin{align}
f:\;&\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
&x \to (x,x+1)
\end{align}
This has a "tuple" output, but that is just a normal element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is much harder to create functions that have tuples of varying sizes as their output, as far as I know the only sensible way would be some kind of tensor product space as the codomain.

thanks so much for your answer! Where you say (...you could represent as a 1 element tuple if you want...), why is it not an n-element tuple?

The co-domain of the operation is just $G$, and you can represent any element of $g$ using a single element of $G$ (just use the element itself!), you could put brackets around this element and call it a tuple if you wanted, but the distinction is not really necessary.

Thx again! OK, I think I know where I am going wrong. I want to cling to the idea that the co-domain of a relation contains tuples of the input domains, because I intuitively understand that definition of a relation as being a subset of the Cartesian Product. I then want to transfer that definition to the definition of an operation, but the output seems to not necessarily be a tuple (even though it's a kind of a kind of a relation). Do we just get to define the co-domain of an operation as that and forget about the origin-story of a relation? I feel like there should somehow be an equivalence.

If you really want to view a relation as a subset of the Cartesian product, you could view it as the subset $${(g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1}: f(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=g_{n+1}} \subset G^{n+1}}$$ This is just the graph of $f$, and the last element in any tuple is the output of the realtion on the first n elements of that tuple.

Ok thanks. I think I get it. I'm going to mull that over. Cheers.

Perhaps an example will help. The "operation" of addition of integers starts with a pair of integers and produces an integer. You can think of that as a function
$$
+ : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}  
$$
with domain $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and codomain $\mathbb{Z}$.
If you want to think of that function formally as a relation then it is a subset of the cartesian product
$$
( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z} .
$$

Actually, that does help me think about it. thanks!
